# gitlab-runner problem demon Docker .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Not run docker demon with gitlab-runner, i use this configuration:

```
test-banks-api:
  stage: ci
  image: docker
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - cd services/banks       
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_TOKEN" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
```

result:

```
$ echo "$CI_REGISTRY_TOKEN" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on 161.97.189.51:53: no such host
```

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com shared runners or a self-hosted runner? If self-hosted, please tell us about your runner configuration (sharing the config file would likely be helpful).

Comment: self-hosted, my configuration config.toml:
check_interval = 0
[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-amd-fra1-01"
  url = "ZZZZZZZZZ"
  token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    shm_size = 0